# Draw a green marble from a bag that already contains a green or a blue marble.

Tags: probability

> A bag contains one marble which is either green or blue, with equal
> probabilities. A green marble is put in the bag (so there are 2
> marbles now), and then a random marble is taken out. The marble taken
> out is green. What is the probability that the remaining marble is
> also green?

Source: Stat 110, Joe Blitzstein

[The solution by the instructor uses the Law of Total Probability but I do not intend to use that.]

Attempt: Denote by $XY$ marble of colour $X$ remains in the bag and the marble of colour $Y$ is taken out. The possibilities are $GG, BG$ and $GB$ out of which the first two are events that we consider. This gives us $P = \frac{2}{3}$ which matches the answer.

My doubt is $GG$ occurs with twice the probability of that of $BG$ (or $GB$) since when both are green, you either take out the marble that you introduced later or you take out the one that's lying inside since the beginning of the experiment. How is that not influencing the result?

Edit: While writing this, I forgot both marbles are supposed to be green and not that just a green marble is to be taken out. So in that case, Favourable : $\{G_1G_2,G_2G_1\}$, Possible - $\{G_1G_2,G_2G_1,BG\}$.

Comment: Your reasoning to calculate P(=2/3) is not correct. You need to find the probability that the remaining marble is also green given that the marble drawn is green. But in favourable cases ,you are considering BG also which you shouldn't because in that case either a green marble would be drawn or a green would be left (both cannot be done simultaneously.

Comment: You should use Baye's theorem instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional probability regarding drawing a marble](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462666/conditional-probability-regarding-drawing-a-marble)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt has two mistakes, but coincidentally arrives at the right answer.

Mistake 1: the three outcomes $GG$, $BG$, $GB$ are not equally probable. The first outcome has probability $1/2$ (as long as the original marble is green, this will happen). The other two outcomes happen with probability $1/4$ each.

Mistake 2: The problem is really asking for a conditional probability (namely, probability of the remaining marble being green *conditioning* on the event that you drew a green marble). You only computed the probability that the other marble is green (using the incorrect probabilities from Mistake 1), and ignored the fact that you drew a green marble as well. Using the correct probabilities above, we have $\frac{P(GG)}{P(GG) + P(BG)} = \frac{1/2}{1/2 + 1/4} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But still, how can we list the favourable outcomes and the possible outcomes? Using the same notation: Favourable - $\{G_1G_2, G_2G_1\}$, Possible - $\{G_1G_2, G_2G_1, BG\}$. Sorry, I actually meant this in the post. While writing this, I forgot both marbles are supposed to be green and not that just a green marble is to be taken out.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus In your new notation, each outcome is equiprobable, so you get $2/3$ (two favorable outcomes out of three possible outcomes).

Comment: Exactly. Now I don't even know why I posted this question. But I'll accept your answer, it addresses the question I **wrote** very precisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have drawn a green marble. If the remaining marble is also green, it implies that the bag originally had a green marble. So we want to compute the conditional probability:
p = P(original marble was green | green marble was drawn).

Let's use Bayes's rule:
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(AB) + P(A^cB)}$

where $A$ and $B$ are some events and $A^c$ is the complement of $A$.

Let's define:
$A$ = original marble was green ($A^c$ = original marble was blue),

$B$ = green marble was drawn,

$P(A) = 1/2$, as given in the problem.

Then we deduce that:

$P(A^c) = 1 - P(A) = 1/2$.

$P(B|A) = 1$, since in this case the bag will contain 2 green marbles.

$P(B|A^c) = 1/2$, since in this case the bag contains 1 green and 1 blue marble.

$P(AB) = P(B|A)P(A) = 1 \times 1/2 = 1/2$

$P(A^cB) = P(B|A^c)P(A^c) = 1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$

Substituting in our formula for $P(A|B)$, we get: $P(A|B) = \dfrac{1 \times 1/2}{1/2 + 1/4} = {2 \over 3}$.

A bit tedious, but it helps to go through the details. Also, intuitively it makes sense that the act of drawing a green marble increases the prior probability of the original marble being green.

Comment: Hi, (+1) thanks for the explanation but as I said, I needed an explanation of why my reasoning was incorrect. Additionally, I wrote the question incorrectly—I have added a note below the original post. But may I ask if $A$ can be replaced with "marble that remains is green". It doesn't matter, I feel.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Yes you should be able to define the events in a different way and still follow Baye's rule to get to the same result. It is really useful to think in terms of conditional probability though, as others have already pointed out.

Comment: I meant, aren't they both exactly same events?